# Collections in Protocol Buffers messages?

Tags: protocol-buffers

In protocol buffers is there a way to have a message with collection of nested messages?  For example a message Supervisor might have a collection of Employees along with the name and department of the supervisor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. You use `repeated` fields;

```
message Employee
{
    ...
}

message Supervisor
{
    repeated Employee employees = 1;
}
```

You can then access the `employees` field as a list.